# Get value from ASP.NET GridView with TextBox on Datatable with Pagination

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, pagination

I am trying to get the value from a textbox inside a gridview that is using a datatable with pagination.

It shows the first 10 rows of the datatable even though there are 50+ rows inside the gridview.

I have a textbox for each row that when you add a value to it, it checks to see if the value exists then adds the value into the database as a quantity.

My Code works, however it is only able to see the textbox quantity of the current pagination page it is on instead of all of the values, how do i fix this?

Here is my code:

```
        Dim index As Integer = 0
        Dim row As GridViewRow = gvPartsAvailable.Rows(index)


        For Each oItem As GridViewRow In gvPartsAvailable.Rows

            Dim txt1 As TextBox = CType(oItem.Cells(6).FindControl("txtQty"), TextBox)

            If txt1.Text = "" Then

            Else

                Dim con As SqlClient.SqlConnection
                Dim cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand
                con = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnectionString").ToString)
                con.Open()
                cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_TMGGoodsOrderDetail] ([OrderID], [PartNumber], [Line], [Description], [Description2], [Price], [Quantity]" &
                ") VALUES (@OrderID, @PartNumber, @Line, @Description, @Description2, @Price, @Quantity)"
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderID", ID)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartNumber", oItem.Cells(1).Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Line", oItem.Cells(2).Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", oItem.Cells(3).Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description2", oItem.Cells(4).Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", oItem.Cells(5).Text.Replace("$", ""))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", txt1.Text)

                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()

            End If

        Next
```